# Android determine start of move without GPS

Tags: android, accelerometer, move

How can I determinate the time-moment when the motion is start without GPS?

I think to I able to determinate it,  with built in acceleration sensor, but I don't know how much are the response time between start of move and the device is realize the move.
The acceleration sensor inaccurate a little, I need to filtering the values maybe with low pass filter.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on sampling rate ( sensor speed )   it  may detgect movement really fast  - some 20 milliseconds - but it is highly dependent on device.   At least motorola defy  sends sensor events only when there is a movement in slower sensor speeds.  ( like  UI )

You may grab this project and play around a little:

https://github.com/ko5tik/accanalyser

(  compiled and signed apk: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.pribluda.android.accanalyzer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImRlLnByaWJsdWRhLmFuZHJvaWQuYWNjYW5hbHl6ZXIiXQ.. )

Answer (score 0):

You are right you need to filter accelerometer values with low pass filter.

Time delay will depend on you filter delay (Order of filter) and frequency of Accelerometer.

Anyhow it will be less than 1 second.